# Point color (col) and fill color (bg) by group in stripchart

Tags: r, plot, colors

I'm trying to reproduce the following image [image http://www.davidzeleny.net/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php/vizualizace:figures:boxplots-jitter-rdbu-colors.png?cache=](http://www.davidzeleny.net/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php/vizualizace:figures:boxplots-jitter-rdbu-colors.png?cache=)

The code I'm using is roughly this:

```
library(RColorBrewer) 
library(reshape2)

a=rnorm(100, mean=1)
b=rnorm(100, mean=0, sd=1)
ab=data.frame(a,b)
melt=melt(ab)
bpColor=brewer.pal(4, 'RdBu')

boxplot(melt$value ~ melt$variable, notch=T, col=c(bpColor[1], bpColor[4]), outline=F, varwidth=T)
stripchart(melt$value ~ melt$variable, add=T, vertical=T, pch=21,
         bg=bpColor[2:3][melt$variable], method='jitter', jitter=0.02)
```

What I'm getting from this is almost the same except for the color of the stripchart points

[my_image http://is.muni.cz/de/256262/Rplot.png](http://is.muni.cz/de/256262/Rplot.png)

How should I edit my code in order to reproduce the proper coloring?
I thought, that

```
bg=bpColor[2:3][melt$variable]
```

would do the job, however I'm getting this output, if I would erase the [] brackets I got two colors, but mixed within the groups. Thank you advance for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not the most elegant way, but hey, it's working

```
boxplot(melt$value ~ melt$variable, notch=T, col=c(bpColor[1], bpColor[4]), outline=F, varwidth=T)
stripchart(melt[melt$variable == "a", "value"] ~ melt[melt$variable == "a", "variable"], add=T, vertical=T, pch=21, bg=c(bpColor[2]), method='jitter', jitter=0.02)
stripchart(melt[melt$variable == "b", "value"] ~ melt[melt$variable == "b", "variable"], add=T, vertical=T, pch=21, bg=c(bpColor[3]), method='jitter', jitter=0.02)
```

[image]

Comment: You're right David it works, however I'd rather have it in the elegant way, since I have no idea why this 'filtering' technique is not working in this particular example. It is working for other cases, so why not now? I'll wait for a while if anyone else will respond and if not, I'll mark it as answered. Thanks!

Comment: Makes sense, I'd do the same.

Comment: No one seems to shed some light into the problem, but anyway as you have said it worked :)

Answer (score 6):

This was supposed to be a short comment, but it grew a little bit too big. I don't answer your question, but I hope to provide some insight in the behaviour of `col` and `bg` in `stripchart`.

I note two things which seem to explain your issue:

(1) colours in the `col` and `bg` arguments are 'allocated' to the points differently. The `col` colours are used row-wise, whereas `bg` colours are allocated to the points column-wise.

(2) Only as many colours that are needed to for the points in one row (for `col` colours) or column (for `bg` colours) are picked from the colour vector, then they are recycled. Together the allocation and recycling rules for `bg` implies that it is tricky to map `bg` colours to different levels of `x`.

```
# a very simple data set to make it easier to see what's going on
y <- rep(1:3, 3)
x <- rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each = 3)
```

- `col` colours are used row-wise, whereas `bg` colours are used
  column wise

  ```
  stripchart(y ~ x, pch = 21,
             col = c("red", "orange", "yellow"),
             bg = rep(c("white", "grey", "black")),
             vertical = TRUE, cex = 4, lwd = 5)
  ```

[image]

- Only the first three `col` colours are used. Then they are re-cycled

  ```
     stripchart(y ~ x, pch = 21,
                col = c("red", "orange", "yellow",
                        "green", "blue", "purple",
                        "white", "grey", "black"),
                bg = rep(c("white", "grey", "black")),
                vertical = TRUE, cex = 4, lwd = 5)`
  ```

[image]

- Only the first three `bg` colours are used. Then they are re-cycled. Thus, 'impossible' to map `bg` colour' to x (grouping varible)

  ```
     stripchart(y ~ x, pch = 21,
                col = c("red", "orange", "yellow"),
                bg = c("white", "grey", "black",
                       "red", "orange", "yellow",
                       "green", "blue", "purple"),
                vertical = TRUE, cex = 4, lwd = 5)
  ```

[image]

Just some further tries:

```
stripchart(y ~ x, pch = 21,
           col = c("red", "orange", "yellow"),
           bg = rep(c("white", "grey", "black"), 3),
           vertical = TRUE, cex = 4, lwd = 5)

stripchart(y ~ x, pch = 21,
           col = c("red", "orange", "yellow"),
           bg = rep(c("white", "grey", "black")),
           vertical = TRUE, cex = 4, lwd = 5)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! This would never crossed my mind, that those types of coloring work other way round. At least my insight into R has been extenden:)

Comment: I was really puzzled by your issue (+1 to your Q by the way) and just had to start to play around with a _really_ simple data set to get the 'logic' of colour allocation, and how it differed between `bg` and `col`.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer to the base but a ggplot approach:

```
ggplot(melt, aes(fill=variable, x=variable, y=value)) +
    geom_boxplot(notch = TRUE) + 
    geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = .05, height =0), shape=21, size=1.5) +
    scale_fill_hue(l=40)
```

I couldn't figure out how to make the hue for the box fill and the point separate.  Thought alpha might work but we want to change points to less intensity not more transparent.  I'd appreciate an edit here for someone to fill in the missing piece.

[image]

Comment: Asked the hue question as a separate question to gain attention from ggplot2 users: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921923/ggplot-change-hue-differently-for-2-geoms-covering-same-grouping